# Quadratic form property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that for given quadratic form $Q$ matrix $B$ (matrix $B$ represents quadratic form $Q$ in some fixed basis), in case of (-B) being quadratic form Q matrix in some different basis (so both B and (-B) are Q's matrices, however basis B and (-B) operating on is not the same), number of positive and negative terms (so-called inertial indices) is equal: $I_{+}=I_{-}$. (of course it is clear, that number of inertial indices is equal across all basises in terms of specified quadratic form)

If any part of condition remains unclear please comment below.

P.S We have only learned about Lagrange and Jacobi methods to reduce quadratic form, however don't understand how to apply them here..
In my opinion, solution should be contradiction form of proof, however even if we suggest that $I_+ \neq I_-$, don't see any consequences to compose proof with. Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q = \vec{x}^TB\vec{x} + \vec{b}$

From the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) we know that $B$ is diagonalizable and $B = P^TDP$

$-B = -P^TDP = P^T(-D)P$

What can you then say about the inertial indices of $B$ and $-B$?

Comment: And P here is transformation matrix? Or P is equal to $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$?

Comment: Transformation matrix, I'll edit this to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Hm, so you express both B and -B via $D$ and $-D$ (which is $diag(1,1,...,1,1)$ and $diag(-1,-1,...,-1,-1)$) and the idea is to try connect that with Lagrange algorithm I guess?

Comment: Or Jacobi one would me more appropriate as in Jacobi method we use determinants, which will turn into negative ones one by one (every single line turned into negative one changes determinant sign), so as in Jacobi coefs are expressed as $\frac{\delta_{n-1}}{\delta_{n-2}}$, and only one of two consequent delta-s would change its sign all coefs in canonical form will turn their signs to negative, is that correct path?

Comment: It's even simpler than that. What is the relation between the inertial indices and $D$?

Comment: Direct, the number of positive elements on diagonal is equal to $I_+$, the same goes for negative ones.

Comment: Oh, from that said we may conclude that number of positive inertial indices in case of B is equal to negative ones, and vice versa , moreover as I've stated in the post, $I_+$ and $I_-$ are equal across all basises in terms of specific quadratic form $Q$, so from that we get needed equality: $I_+=I_-$. Like that?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right!

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it

Answer (score 1):

BY theorem $I_+$ is the number of positive eigenvalues of any representative matrix $B$, and $I_-$  is the number of negative eigenvalues of $B$. Now, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $-B$ , and the multiplicties are the same.

It is now easy to conclude.

Comment: Sounds good to me, but do not understand it fully, may you expand your idea a little, please